# Angular 5 - need to create multiple rows inside a table

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap-3, ngfor

I have the following component.ts file.

```
selector: 'app-product-search',
template: `
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <table class="table table-bordered">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>SKU</th>
                    <th>MRP</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                    <my-product-list [product]="product" *ngFor="let product of products | product: searchText">
                   </my-product-list>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
`
```

And the following HTML file.

```
<tr>
    <td>{{ product.SKU }}</td>
    <td>{{ product.mrp }}</td>
</tr>
```

The output HTML comes as a single row compressed inside a single column.

```
 SKU           MRP
 ABC749XYZ849
```

The ideal output should be.

```
 SKU           MRP
 ABC           749
 XYZ           849
```

I am not sure why I am getting this strange behavior.

Comment: would you please share the code of my-product-list component

Comment: @AbdelrhmanHussien, its the`tr td` tag in the question

Comment: and the JS code ??

Comment: @AbdelrhmanHussien, i have used `*ngFor`

Comment: don't you have any JS in this component  ??

Comment: A tbody is supposed to contain tr. Not tr inside a my-product-list element. Drop this component and inline the tr in the tbody.

Comment: I don't think you should create a component for simple tr like this. I think wrapping it that component cause that unexpected behavior just tried without the component and see what you get

Comment: @JBNizet, can you show how?

Comment: @AbdelrhmanHussien, ok, can you show how?

Comment: `<tbody><tr *ngFor="let product of products | product: searchText"><td>{{ product.SKU }}</td><td>{{ product.mrp }}</td></tr></tbody>`

Comment: @JBNizet, this is perfect